# Why do both struct timeval with different sizes work when calling select on the same ARM64 Linux?

Tags: linux, arm, compatibility, 32bit-64bit, arm64

I used an ARMv7 and an ARMv8 toolchain to compile the same .c file as shown below. Then I ran the two produced programs (`select32` and `select64`) on an ARM64 Linux using QEMU.

```c
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval t = {10, 999999};

    printf("sizeof timeval is %d, sizeof(tv_sec) is %d, sizeof(tv_usec) is %d\nstart select()\n", 
           (int) sizeof(struct timeval), (int)sizeof(t.tv_sec), (int)sizeof(t.tv_usec));
    select(0,0,0,0, &t);
    printf("select() ends\n");
}
```

I found that both programs slept about 10 seconds between `start select()`and `select() ends`

```
/ # ./select64
sizeof timeval is 16, sizeof(tv_sec) is 8, sizeof(tv_usec) is 8
start select()
select() ends
/ # ./select32
sizeof timeval is 8, sizeof(tv_sec) is 4, sizeof(tv_usec) is 4
start select()
select() ends
```

Why did the 32-bit application also sleep 10 seconds, although (I think) it passed the kernel a form of struct timeval that the kernel didn't expect? Is it some code in the kernel, or some code in the C library, that found out something weird and then converted the struct?

Answer (score 1):

When you compile with a 32-bit toolchain, the members of `struct timeval` are 32 bit, and when you compile with a 64-bit toolchain, they're 64 bit.  That means that the values you provided are automatically converted to the appropriate type by the compiler, and the data you passed it is of the right size.

The C compiler will automatically convert values of type `int`, which you've provided, to the appropriate type when using them in a struct initializer if the type used is larger (like `long`, which is probably what's used here under the hood).

The system calls for 32-bit and 64-bit programs differ, so when you call `select` in this case, you're really calling two different system calls, one of which is probably 32-bit EABI and the other, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel distinguishes between 32-bit and 64-bit syscalls. The 32-bit `select` passes a `old_timeval32` or `compat_timeval` structure while the 64-bit `select` passes the `timeval` structure type. The 32-bit one is deprecated due to the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

It is similar with `timespec`: The 32-bit `pselect` passes a `timespec` structure while the 64-bit `pselect` passes a `timespec64` structure. The names differ between the implementations, for example `compat_timespec` for the 32-bit one and `timespec` for the 64-bit one.

Here some pieces of code from the linux kernel used in the Raspberry Pi OS: There are explicit conversion routines in [`compat.c`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/master/kernel/compat.c) to copy data between the two types:

```c
static int compat_put_timeval(struct compat_timeval __user *o,
        struct timeval *i)
{
    return (put_user(i->tv_sec, &o->tv_sec) ||
        put_user(i->tv_usec, &o->tv_usec)) ? -EFAULT : 0;
}
```